# shopping cart images not showing

Tags: magento2

Running magento 2.4.4 w/ Nginx and varnish.
Everything works well except images on my shopping cart are not showing!

I set the permissions of my files correctly.
When I check my source it says this:

http://192.168.1.184/media/catalog/product/cache/b16649c577741285fa75d4653f62d403/i/n/image_file_name.jpg

When I check my server the images are there at the location

/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/b16649c577741285fa75d4653f62d403/i/n/image_file_name.jpg

There is an extra /pub as you can see.

my Nginx relevant config is this

```
location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {

   try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

logs shows nothing.

This is driving me nuts. Beside permission and nginx conf. what else could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your app/etc/env.php file.

```
'directories' => [
    'document_root_is_pub' => true
],
```

I use nginx too. And my document root is the pub directory. In my case, i had to set document_root_is_pub to true, to tell magento, that pub is the document root. check [nginx.conf.sample](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/nginx.conf.sample) Line 32

```
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue. I actually found it prior to your answer since my nginx config was changed after an update of magento. Thank you!